# expo publish fails when using an absolute path

Tags: expo

I am using expo-cli 2.1.2.

I have defined an absolute path in my .babelrc file as following:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
          ["transform-react-jsx-source"],
          ["module-resolver", {
            "alias": {
              "abs": "./src",
            }
          }]
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to build and test with this file. However, when I try to publish, the metro bundler fails to resolve the absolute path:

```
Unable to resolve "abs/services/firebaseInit" from "App.js"
```

Where App.js is in the top directory, and the failure is for the following line:

```
import firebaseInit from 'mypet/services/firebaseInit';
```

(`firebaseInit` is defined in `src\services\firebaseInit.js`)

Any idea how to solve this?

*Also posted in https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/105*

Comment: Maybe because you've put it under "development" env? And when you try to publish you probably use production environment

Comment: Doesn't help. Did you try it?